# Failing to create several conditions in the 'multiverse' package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use three different threshold methods on my data, utilizing the [multiverse package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multiverse/readme/README.html). I have boiled down the code to a reproducible example:

```
#import packages
library(multiverse)
library(pracma) # for findpeaks function

# create random data of 100 Scores between 0 and 10
set.seed(1234)  
Score <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 10)

#create multiverse object
M = multiverse()

# Create parameter 'threshold' with 3 possible conditions
inside(M, {
Peaks <- branch(threshold,
               "two_highest" ~ as.data.frame(findpeaks(x = Score, sortstr = TRUE, minpeakdistance = 10)[1:2,]),
               "threshold_1" ~ as.data.frame(findpeaks(x = Score, minpeakheight = 3, sortstr = FALSE, minpeakdistance = 10)),
               "threshold_2" ~ as.data.frame(findpeaks(x = Score, minpeakheight = 6, sortstr = FALSE, minpeakdistance = 10)))
})

parameters(M) # list of parameters checks out
multiverse::expand(M) # analysis paths

# extracting the Peaks variable to see whether it worked
test <- M %>%
 extract_variables(Peaks)

test # only the first entry has a dataframe
test[1,]$Peaks
test[2,]$Peaks
test[3,]$Peaks

# outside of the multiverse, these functions do not produce NAs
as.data.frame(findpeaks(x = Score, sortstr = TRUE, minpeakdistance = 10)[1:2,])
as.data.frame(findpeaks(x = Score, minpeakheight = 3, sortstr = FALSE, minpeakdistance = 10))
```

As you can see, only the first condition/threshold produces an output. I have tried running the findpeaks() function within and outside of the branch() function. I feel like I am not understanding how to access multiverse variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code that defines the multiverse (here with the `inside()` function), it automatically runs the first option of every branch, and that's the output that you're getting. In order to run the full multiverse, you need need to also run the command `multiverse::execute_multiverse(M)`. In your script that could go right after the `inside` code bit, or right after you check the parameters and analysis paths.